# How come I can .hide() but not .show() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">my box</div>​
```

How come I can hide a visible div like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/FfaVW/2/

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    visibility:visible;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery('#box').hide();​
```

But I can't show an hidden div like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/FfaVW/1/

**CSS:**

```
#box {
    visibility:hidden;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery('#box').show();​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

show() alters the *display* CSS property, not *visibility*.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

It will show a display: none for example.

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Offers insight as to why jQuery behaves this way:

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

Comment: @Yarin No problem.  I was actually quite surprised to see that jQuery behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `show()` and `hide()` alter the `display`.

display modifies the flow of the elements on the screen.

visibility just deals with the fact that whether you can see it on screen or not, but it will take space.

check the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/XS4ca/3/

Answer (score 0):

Dont Use `visibility` CSS for `Show` and `Hide` `Div`.

Instead Use `Div` Hide using `Css` you use `Display:none` and For Show use `Displan:Block`

Show Following Links For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/FfaVW/7/

http://jsfiddle.net/FfaVW/8/

Hope this is helpful for you.